# Using a database or table structure within program

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

Basically all I want is to be able to create like a self contained database in my Windows Forms application, I do not want to connect to a server or anything like that with SQL Server, I just want like a small database in the application that can handle a few transactions.

Like for instance if I create a Windows Forms application then it would have its own small database in it and when deploying it.. it will save rows there and stuff. I remember hearing about a plug in, it started with a CT or something don't recall, but it would be a plugin for Visual Studio.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Check out http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: Sql server compact (embedded) edition would  fit your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) or [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) (ADO.NET provider is available [here](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)). Both are embedded database engines that run in-process. You don't need to install anything, just include the appropriate DLLs with your application.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has no problem providing you with just such a database. Just right click your project, add new item, and select SQL Server Database. The database created will be part of your project and can be deployed as needed.

Comment: This still relies on SQL Server and won't work if SQL Server is not installed. This is definitely not what the OP wants.

Comment: Actually it relies on SQL Server Express being installed locally; not on a server. OPs requirements are to not need to 'connect to a server or anything like that with MSSQL'. This is right out of the box. Although if a requirement was to not need to include the client files in the deployment package then yes I would suggest SSC or maybe even a .settings file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a limited amount of data you can just right-click the project and Add a DataSet. Then you can define multiple tables in the .xsd and store multiple rows. in the .xml.  Then you can write some simple code in the .xsd code-behind to auto load and save defaults and even pull back rows of data. I typically use this approach for storing a single record in each table. It will also work with multiple records in each table. There's a point where if you start to get a lot of data you'll probably wish you had used something like SQL Compact Edition or something similar that you bundle with your app.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sqlLite,this is the website 
http://www.sqlite.org/
or you can use access too